# mysql 5.7.10 performance 3 Times Slower vs 5.6.28

Tags: mysql, performance

This weekend I rolled back my database from 5.7.10 to 5.6.28. In a test load of 27 million records with inserts of multi-writes, the MySQL 5.7.10 took 120 minutes to load this database. On the same machine, 5.6.28 took 40 minutes. This is a repeatable event. The test was done on a Windows 7 Professional machine having 64GB of memory. And it was done on a Server with Windows Serve 2012 R2 with 256 GB of memory.

This was not the only problem. The group by statement fails to operate on a sub query and always operates on the table inside the query.
Example:

```
select * from (select * from tablename order by datex desc, timex desc ) as A 
group by recordx;
```

This query should pull the first record of the A Table as in 5.6.28. In 5.70.10, the query pulls out the earliest record entered from tablename and NOT A. Even when desc is replaced with asc, the result is the same.

5.6.28 always picks up the top element in the "A" table of the subquery.

MySQL needs some explaining to do with respect to their claim of 5.7.10 being 3x faster. It is definitely not backward compatible either as demonstrated by the "group by" behaviour.

Comment: about the top element, the behaviour of 5.6.28 is not documented, the documentation says that an arbitrary element will be returned, you can't rely on it not even on 5.6.

Comment: The developers would like to hear about the performance degradation; please submit a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .  (You will need to be more specific about how the data was loaded, plus cache size settings.)

Comment: What is `*` supposed to return for any row except `recordx`? It sounds like you depended on accidental compilation and behaviour up to now. If there is a bug, it's that this syntax doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer does not address the performance issue (I think more information is needed and that should be a separate question.  It addresses the query issue.

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) is quite explicit that this query:

```
select *
from (select * from tablename order by datex desc, timex desc ) as A
group by recordx
```

produces indeterminate results.  Here is the relevant quote:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they
>   are the same, the values chosen are **indeterminate**. Furthermore,
>   the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding
>   an `ORDER BY` clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been
>   chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values within each group
>   the server chooses.

It is a shame that your developers used code that is explicitly documented not to work correctly.  You should fix the code.

One fix is:

```
select * 
from tablename
where not exists (select 1
                  from tablename t2
                  where t2.recordx = t.recordx and
                        (t2.datex > t.datex or
                         t2.datex = t.datex and t2.timex > t.timex
                        )
                 );
```

Comment: 9.5.1 GROUP BY and Sorting
In MySQL, a GROUP BY clause has the side effect of sorting rows. If you already have a GROUP BY clause in your query that produces the desired sort order, there’s no need for an ORDER BY. Use of ORDER BY is necessary with GROUP BY only to produce a different sort order than that resulting from the GROUP BY. However, this isn’t a portable behavior. For database engines other than MySQL, GROUP BY might not sort rows. To write more portable queries, add an ORDER BY even if MySQL does not require it.

Comment: The above quote is from The MySQL Certification Study guide of 2005. The word indeterminate is never used in describing GROUP By. The only warning is one of portability. The behaviour of group by has not changed since 5.1 until the 5.7.10 release. The reference manual clearly states the indeterminacy but educational materials by MySQL and other authors do not emphasize this when teaching MySQL. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: And it would be prudent to follow your advice and  re-write any such queries. However, for now, 5.6.28 is offering a huge performance over 5.7.10. Once 5.7 hits the 3X it states, it would be worth while to modify the few group queries I have . Again, thanks for the clarification and the example.

Comment: Elsewhere, MySQL points out that the ordering of a `GROUP BY` is deterministic, but it goes on to say that this is "non-standard" and says you need `ORDER BY NULL` to _inhibit_ the implicit ordering.

Comment: If your table is large, Gordon's suggestion is likely to be slow.  [My groupwise max blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) discusses other techniques.

Comment: @user3470332 that query shouldn't compile at all, whether it's part of a certification guide or not. What is `*` supposed to do when grouping? Which arbitrary aggregate did it choose for all columns *except* `recordx` ? If that certification guide doesn't mention that this is a huge problem, you should dump it. In the recycle bin, to atone for the harm it's already done

Answer (score 0):

Durability defaults have been changed between 5.6 and 5.7.
Sync_binlog is now enabled by default (see http://lefred.be/content/sync_binlog-1-in-5-7/)

This of course affects performance, certainly if raid cache is not used.

If you are not concerned by having your binarylogs in sync after each commit, please disable it again.